# ChatGPT Plus seemingly gives access to more sophisticated models than I can access via the API? /confused

Tags: open-ai

I've spent the past day researching different AI models and have come to the conclusion that I am overpaying at $20 per month for a ChatGPT Plus subscription, since the consensus seems to be that I can get the same service just using their API via a front end UI (I have set up [LibreChat](https://docs.librechat.ai) for this purpose and fed it my API keys). I was under the impression this would give me the access to the same latest ChatGPT model as I converse with in a ChatGPT Plus window? At the time of writing, this is apparently `gpt-4-0125-preview`.

**However**, when I interrogated the AI about its training data (via the API / LibreChat) as a test, (ostensibly gpt-4-0125-preview), it tells me its training data is only made up until September 2021? (Figure 1)

Asking the same question in the ChatGPT Plus window, the AI tells me it's 2023, as I would expect, according to the official OpenAI docs. (Figures 2 & 3)

Please see the attached screenshots, and tell me what I'm missing here?

Also, if someone could answer this explicitly: does a ChatGPT Plus subscription give me something that the API doesn't? What is the difference? I'm confused... and really, I've wasted enough time with this now. I've spent most of my Saturday setting up LibreChat to run on my server at a custom domain, only to find the whole thing apparently provides a significantly lesser service that ChatGPT Plus does after-all. I guess at least I didn't cancel my subscription *just* yet...

[image: Fig 1]
[image: Fig 2]
[image: Fig 3]

Comment: This stackexchange is for the discussion of AI, not pre-trained models or their use.  The genai stackexchange is probably better suited for this question.

Comment: please do not put question marks on end of statements ... that is not how questions are formed